# Regular expression to filter out "\{" but allow "{"

Tags: java, regex

I am trying for regular expression to get following thing

**Input-**

```
{foo}
{bar}
\{notgood}
\{bad}
{nice}
\{bad}
```

**Output-**

```
foo
bar
nice
```

I want to find all strings starting with `{` but NOT with `\{`.
I have only five words as input.

I tried a regular expression i.e. `"\\{(foo|bar|nice|notgood|bad)"` which gives all words starting with `{`. I don't know how to get rid of `\{`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure that a `{` is only matched if no `\` precedes it:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "(?<!\\\\)   # Assert no preceding backslash\n" +
    "\\{         # Match a {\n" +
    "(foo|bar|nice|notgood|bad) # Match a keyword\n" +
    "\\}         # Match a }", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
}
```

`matchList` will then contain `["foo", "bar", "nice"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 'group-match' string for that, as in the following code:

```
str.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\{(foo|bar|nice|notgood|bad)\\}", "$1");
```

the `$1` refers to the first `()` group in the input

for `str = "{foo} \{bar} {something}"` it will give you `foo \{bar} {something}`